# Export the VisualSVN Server User Access Rights Using WMI in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi, visualsvn-server, wmi-query

I need to console application to load the VisualSVN Server User Access Rights to the excel file.

Initially, I started with VBScript to do this. But in VBScript it is very hard to compare two csv files. So currently I'm looking into C#.

Is any sample to code to do this in C# like VBScript in "http://www.svnforum.org/threads/38790-Access-Rights-Reporting-in-Subversion-or-Viusal-SVN"?

If it is quit easy in PowerShell, We will consider PowerShell too. But I don't have experience with PowerShell. Can anyone please redirect me to the Sample code to do the same.

Comment: Have you considered PowerShell for this task? It's pretty good with CSV.

Comment: @bahrep If it is quit easy in PowerShell, We will consider PowerShell also. Can u please redirect me to the sample code, because i don't know about PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

VisualSVN Server 3.4 comes with a [PowerShell module](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/powershell/) which provides a number of cmdlets for server and repository administration (works locally or remotely).

Getting a list of access rules with VisualSVN Server 3.4 is as simple as running [`Get-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Get-SvnAccessRule) cmdlet in PowerShell.

For the complete list of PowerShell cmdlets and usage examples, read the article [VisualSVN Server PowerShell Cmdlet Reference](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/).